# Connection timed out while connecting to database of another website

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've wrote a PHP page on my localhost (XAMPP) which connects to an online MySQL server (I got a host and I used its Database, already put % on Remote MySQL®) and shows a table. It worked fine with below code:

```
$server= 'harfenaab.ir:3306';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'pass';
$db = 'mydatabase';
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db);
```

It gets connected and reads and writes perfect. But when I uploaded it to my other host (totally different from the one with database), it gets timed out. The code is exactly the same as it is in my localhost, but it doesn't work on my host.
See: http://azarsat.blue/class_plugins.php

THE ERROR IS:

> connection failed:Connection timed out

Comment: Have you checked if your second host can connect to your remote MySQL server via port 3306? It is worth to check the firewall setting of your remote MySQL server, it might not allow your second host to connect with.

Comment: can you ping the server 'harfenaab.ir' from your other host?

Comment: @SimonMC.Cheng , Nice Idea, how should I check it on the host? I got access to Cpanel of the First Host (my database is on this host) and to Direct Admin of second host (my php page is on this host).

Comment: While I am finding out how to check open ports via cpanel, can you try two things from your second host and report the test results? 1. ping harfenaab.ir, 2. nslookup harfenaab.ir

Comment: @SimonMC.Cheng , sure, thank you, this is ping test of site24x7: https://www.site24x7.com/public/t/results-1470677410120.html 

NS Lookup: http://whois.nic.ir/?name=harfenaab.ir

Comment: Have you checked the mysql bind address ?

Comment: @user3885927 , Actually I got a report on that : https://www.site24x7.com/public/t/results-1470677410120.html , any help?

Comment: @frz3993 : not actually, how should I?

Comment: It's in the mysql config file, `my.cnf`. Requires root privilege. But I don't know how to using cpanel.

Comment: @user2971833, you should perform the test under your server but not from the webtools...